# Creat array of JSON objects from mulitple objects using linq.js

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I have a JSON array like so:

```
var jsonArray = [
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Large", Type:"a", Value: "100"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Medium", Type:"a", Value: "160"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Small", Type:"a", Value: "200"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Large", Type:"b", Value: "400"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Medium", Type:"b", Value: "120"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Small", Type:"b", Value: "170"}
]
```

I have been using linq.js and I am trying to manipulate the above JSON so the 6 objects are turned into 2, so I am left with an Array like below:

```
var desiredArray = [

    { Date: "2010-02-25", Large:"100", Medium: "160", Small: "200", Type:"a" }
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Large:"400", Medium: "120", Small: "170", Type:"b" }

]
```

But this is the first time I have ever used linq. I have spent quite a while trying to figure it out but I really dont know how to start it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: JSON is a STRING format. You don't work with JSON (strings). You work with native Javascript objects.

Comment: That linq library is painful to use. Did you look at the tests available for it? You should probably start there and come back if you get stuck implementing it. Too much magic string is bad for the soul.

Comment: @TravisJ What's so painful about it?

Comment: @JLRishe - The use of magic strings and eval (by way of new Function(string). I would have to test it, but I do not think that the OrderBy is properly deferring execution. I think each individual method may be lazily executed, but it does not seem to defer execution. Instead, it composes a new Enumerable each pass which is not how actual yield works. The injected use of `$` makes the code slightly harder to implement as it introduces the idea of wildcards. Selecting requires an object to inject from string creation, and is not a true projetion. etc etc etc

Comment: @TravisJ Three of your points seem to be about the use of string expressions, which are optional. linq.js supports using ordinary functions. I'm not sure what you mean on the other points. It seems to defer execution just fine as far as I can tell: http://jsfiddle.net/vr46j0vv/ Each IEnumerator uses a Yielder internally, which is a mutable object that iterates through values and returns each one in turn. I don't see the creation of a new Enumerable on each pass. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish this:

```js
var jsonArray = [
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Large", Type:"a", Value: "100"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Medium", Type:"a", Value: "160"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Small", Type:"a", Value: "200"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Large", Type:"b", Value: "400"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Medium", Type:"b", Value: "120"},
    { Date: "2010-02-25", Size:"Small", Type:"b", Value: "170"}
];

function makeGroupKey(item) {
    return JSON.stringify({
        Date: item.Date,
        Type: item.Type
    });
}

function mergeItems(items) {
    return items.Aggregate(JSON.parse(items.Key()), function (prev, next) {
        prev[next.Size] = next.Value;
        return prev;
    });
}

var result = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
    .GroupBy(makeGroupKey)
    .Select(mergeItems)
    .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"></script>
```